# How to send email with attachments

Tags: spring, email, email-attachments

I want to send an email with an image attached with it. I am using spring 3 with velocity templates. I am able to do that but for some reasons when I add an extension with the image name I don't get the email delivered.

Following is the code I am using for it:

```
private MimeMessage createEmail(Application application, String templatePath,   String subject, String toEmail, String fromEmail, String fromName) {
    MimeMessage mimeMsg = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("application", application);
    String text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, templatePath, model);
    text = text.replaceAll("\n", "<br>");

    try {

        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMsg, true);
        helper.setSubject(subject);
        helper.setTo(toEmail);

        if (fromName == null) {
            helper.setFrom(fromEmail);
        } else {
            try {
                helper.setFrom(fromEmail, fromName);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                helper.setFrom(fromEmail);
            }
        }

        helper.setSentDate(application.getDateCreated());
        helper.setText(text, true);

        InputStream inputStream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("images/formstack1.jpg");
        helper.addAttachment("formstack1",  new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)));


    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return mimeMsg;
}
```

Using the code above I could add **formstack1** as attachment but it has no extension so I don't get the **formstack1.jpg** image file. But when I use **formstack1.jpg** for the name of resource to be attached in `helper.addAttachment("formstack1",  new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)));` as formstack1 changed to `formstack1.jpg` I don't get even the email delivered. I am using `smtp.gmail.com` and `25` for port. I do get the email sent successfully message on the console though. But the email
is never delivered.

**EDIT:** If I keep it like `helper.addAttachment("formstack1",  new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)));` and change the extension from nothing to .jpg while downloading the attached image I do get the desired image.

Could someone help me understand why is it happening and how send email with 1 or more attachments using spring 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should better use Apache Commons HtmlEMail

http://commons.apache.org/email/userguide.html

Comment: Can't get the `commons-email-1.3` version and the maven repository has only `commons-email-1.1` as latest. Am I missing something? http://apache.techartifact.com/mirror//commons/email/binaries/commons-email-1.3-bin.zip is the download link for that.

Comment: Looks like `.jpg` images don't fit into the spec even after setting the content type as `image/jpeg` it didn't work. But when I tried a `.png` everything worked alright.